# Por que tantas pastas com o nome "Drawable" no Android?

Tags: android, imagem

Eu tenho uma dúvida boba. Já sei que as pastas *Drawable* no **Android** é para pôr as imagens com as resoluções referentes. Por exemplo, a pasta *drawable-ldpi* é para pôr as imagens com resolução baixa.

*Mas a minha pergunta é a seguinte:* Quando eu for fazer uma imagem para colocar em algum aplicativo eu precisarei criá-la em várias resoluções diferentes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não necessariamente precisa criar várias imagens com resoluções diferentes.
Existe uma transição em relação à resolução das telas dos devices. Daqui a um tempo todos os devices terão a tela com alta resolução. Mas enquanto isso, para dar um melhor design em aparelhos mais antigos e os de resoluções muito altas é, em muitos casos, necessário usar deste artificio.

Existem boas dicas no site do Android:

- http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Geralmente usa se a pasta **drawable-mdpi**, pois é a com mais devices atualmente. Quando não existe imagens para a resolução, caso essa seja diferente, o Android gerencia essa troca.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, quanto a imagens, realmente vc tem que gerar de vários tamanhos diferentes, caso queira que o app funcione bem em diferentes devices, utilizando diversas pastas drawable.

Mas tenho duas dicas pra vc, que são uma mão na roda:

1ª Para construção de ícones para sua aplicação(*icon_launcher/ícones para actionbar/navigation drawer/ ou até mesmo criar um ícone com os padrões do android, a partir de qualquer imagem*) usa esse site [aqui](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) e seja feliz :)

2ª Uma forma (não das mais corretas, mas uma das que melhor funciona) é criar diversas pastas values (exemplos: *values-normal-hdpi/values-normal-mpdi/valuessw600dp*), com um arquivo *styles.xml* diferente para cada uma delas. 
Assim você usa uma única imagem com uma resolução boa e muda o *width* e *height* para cada resolução de tela.
E ainda pode usar esses *styles* como sua própria biblioteca, para usar em outras aplicações.

Se quiser entender melhor, só falar :)

Boa sorte.

Answer (score 1):

É bom você criar várias imagens, uma para cada pasta, uma com resolução baixa, uma média, e assim por diante. Porque assim você vai ganhar maior "elasticidade" para os diferentes tamanhos de aparelhos e resoluções de tela, assim o android vai identificar a imagem que mais é adequada para a resolução do aparelho.

Dê uma lida na documentação que fala sobre isso no: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)