# Design responsivo para aplicativo Android

Tags: android, layout-responsivo

Alguém pode me indicar algum material (livros, sites, ...), sobre design responsivo para android.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com layout responsivo? HTML ou aplicativo que funcione com mais de um formato de tela?

Comment: Aplicativos mesmo nada de HTML ou CSS!

Comment: Tem alguma dúvida específica em relação a algum código que esteja testando?

Comment: Eu quero estuda do zero mesmo, já busquei na web mas não vi nada de código só teoria é bla bla nada de codigo!

Comment: @Marcelo não tem muita coisa não porque geralmente a pessoa faz vários layouts ou vários aplicativos. Não tem muito milagre não. O que tem é como fazer um aplicativo ter vários layouts diferentes para vários tamanhos e formatos de tela. (hdpi, mdpi, etc)

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta/resposta aqui: [Porque tantas pastas com o nome Drawable no Android](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12971/por-que-tantas-pastas-com-o-nome-drawable-no-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rapaz, acho que você está perdido com relação ao básico da programação Android.
Responsivo é um termo normalmente utilizado para construção de sites e webapps, para quando ele se adapta à diferentes tamanhos de tela.

Na programação mobile, utilizando o SDK, para o funcionamento de uma aplicação em diferentes tamanhos de tela, há a configuração do layout da aplicação para cada resolução que queira que o app funcione.

Não sei como é o seu inglês, mas esse é um bom artigo
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Para essa adpatação de tela realmente não é muito código não, no geral montamos a tela através de um *.xml dentro da pasta de layout e setamos as imagens e elementos utilizados que ele utilizará.

Cada pasta possui uma indicação quanto à resolução de tela que é destinada.
Exemplo:

layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi

drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi

...

Espero ter ajudade em algo!