# Criar layout alternativo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho um projeto e preciso que se ajuste aos diversos tipos de telas, já tentei com o `ConstraintLayout` mais pra o que eu quero não dá certo, pesquisei e achei algo sobre Layout Alternativo. Seria XML's diferente para cada tipo de tela. Como seria?, alguém pode ajudar.

Comment: Aqui tem um material bem interessante para essa dúvida
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13201/design-responsivo-para-aplicativo-android

Comment: Não tirou minha dúvida, já tinha visto esse post. Gostaria de layoust alternativos.

Answer (score 0):

> Existem dispositivos Android de todos os formatos e tamanhos,
>   portanto, o layout do seu app precisa ser flexível. Ou seja, em vez de
>   definir seu layout com dimensões rígidas que pressuponham determinado
>   tamanho e proporção de tela, seu layout precisa responder de forma
>   eficiente a diferentes tamanhos e orientações.

Na documentação do próprio Android, tem um artigo onde fala sobre [Compatibilidade com tamanhos de tela diferentes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities?hl=pt-br). A figura abaixo mostra como a largura da visualização de texto com `match_parent` se ajusta conforme a largura da tela é alterada pela orientação do dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dispositivos com Sistema Operacional Android não só vêm com vários tamanhos de telas (celulares, tablets, TVs etc.) como as telas também têm diferentes tamanhos de pixels. Ou seja, enquanto um dispositivo tem 160 pixels por polegada quadrada, outro encaixa 480 pixels no mesmo espaço. Se você não considerar essas variações em densidade de pixels, o sistema pode dimensionar suas imagens (resultando em imagens borradas) ou as imagens podem aparecer em um tamanho completamente errado.

Veja mais na documentação onde fala sobre [Compatibilidade com densidades de pixel diferentes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Esse posto já tinha visto em outro lugar, ele fala apenas de tipos dos layouts, só que na verdade queria criar layouts alternativos.